# Why does "echo strcmp('60', '100');" in php output 5?

Tags: php, strcmp

PHP's documentation on this function is a bit sparse and I have read that this function compares ASCII values so...

```
echo strcmp('hello', 'hello');
//outputs 0 as expected - strings are equal.
echo '<hr />';

echo strcmp('Hello', 'hello');
//outputs -32, a negative number is expected as 
//uppercase H has a lower ASCII value than lowercase h.
echo '<hr />';

echo strcmp('60', '100');
//outputs 5.
```

The last example is confusing me. I don't understand why it is outputting a positive number.

- ASCII Value of 0 = 48
- ASCII Value of 1 = 49
- ASCII Value of 6 = 54
- Total ASCII value of '60' = (54 + 48) = 102
- Total ASCII value of '100' = (49 + 48 + 48) = 145

The strcmp() functions is saying that '60' is "greater" than '100' even though it seems that the ASCII value *and* string length of '100' is greater than '60'

**Can anyone explain why?**

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns the difference of the first non-matching character between the strings.

`6` - `1` is 5.

When you look at it, you are probably not seeing the characters or digits—just the numbers

Comment: Note that this is not guaranteed behaviour -- the only thing guaranteed is that the value will be larger than zero for these input parameters.

Comment: @SimonRichter:  Agreed it is not guaranteed.  But it *is* traditional.  Some code I wrote in 1978 which depends on this method of computing the return value *still works*!

Comment: @wallyk, how do you know that this answer is correct when the documentation didn't say that it returns the difference of the first character?

Comment: @Pacerier:  I have a lot of experience with a lot of different runtime libraries, from PDP-11s running Unix v6 (the original C), to VAX/VMS, MSDOS, Windows, GCOS, Sequent, IBM, and microcontrollers.  They all implement the difference, which, as some CRTL source code indicates, for tradition and perfect compatibility with the original.

Answer (score 8):

Because `strcmp()` stops at the first difference it finds. Hence the difference between the ASCII value of '1' and the ASCII value of '6'

Comment: @wallyk, how do you know that this behavior is guaranteed when the documentation didn't say that it returns the difference of the first character?

Answer (score 5):

6 is 5 "larger" than 1. This is lexical comparison. The first character is different, that's where the comparison stops.